# Authorize with JsonReult action jQuery ajax returned status code 200 when not authorized

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I have JsonResult action which required authentication and special role

```
[Authorize(Roles = "User")]
public virtual JsonResult Cancel()
{
 //...
}
```

But when for example i log off and hit this action with jQuery ajax i could see that status code is 200, but it is should be 401.

```
$.ajax({
                url: "/Cancel/",
                type:   "POST",
                dataType: "text",
                cache: false,
                success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                    alert(xhr.status); //200 here when unauthorized
                }

});
```

So I really not able to execute the controller logic because it is not authorized, i checked that on debug, but why i am getting status code 200 in jquery ajax?

UPDATED:

In Fiddler it is saying status code **302** and i could see that request to `/Acount/Login` was made after `/Cancel` request.

```
/Cancel - 302
/Acount/Login - 200
```

In Chrome network **Status Code:302 Found** and also i could see that login controller(`/Acount/Login`) getting called after `/Cancel` was called.

```
/Cancel - 302
/Acount/Login - 200
```

Complete request details in Opera network

Could someone explain whats happening, why jquery didn't get correct status code?

Really what i want to do - a want to get correct status code and if it is `401` i want to redirect user to login page (`window.location.href = " /Acount/Login"`)

**Request details**

```
POST /Cancel/ HTTP/1.1 
User-Agent: Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; U; en) Presto/2.9.168 Version/11.50
Host: localhost:999
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://localhost:999/Action
Cookie: style=normalText; ASP.NET_SessionId=latzewpi3kqmkq4meljv0ln5
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 0
Accept: text/plain, */*; q=0.01
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
```

**Response details**

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found 
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: /Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2fCancel%2f
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 3.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 11 Aug 2011 03:04:53 GMT
Content-Length: 169
```

Answer (score 0):

`FormsAuthentication` have handler in its http module, that will redirect all 401 responses to login page instead of error page.

Looking at source code of `FormsAuthenticationModule` there should be (quite ugly) workaround - if you append `ReturnUrl=/` to your query string, the module should do no redirection.

The best solution is probably to write own http module for authentication - you can open `FormsAuthenticationModule` in reflector and use it as reference.